# Display number of sold variation product in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I made **variation product** (ticket) in WooCommerce and I need to display how many tickets of its variations Ive already sold.

So for example Ive got 1 ticket which has two variations: 
'**male**' and '**female**'.

There is any chance I can get counter for each variation ticket sold and display it on my page? So other customers can see how many tickets are bought by males and how many by famales.

**EDIT
I don't really know much about php, but to be more specific:

I made product with variations. So when customers buying it, they can choose between Male and Female. There is 10 tickets for Male and 10 for Females (20 total). I want to display number of product bought by Males and Females, separately.

Ive got something like this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'wc_product_sold_count', 11 );
function wc_product_sold_count() {
    global $product;            
    $units_sold = get_post_meta( $product->id, 'total_sales', true );           
    echo '<p>' . sprintf( __( 'Units Sold: %s', 'woocommerce' ), $units_sold ) . '</p>';
}
```

But first of all its for number of total sold product, not their variations. Secondly it will display in single product page, there is chance to put it somewhere else?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is vague. But to answer your question in its current form, you just have to loop each of the variations and display or echo out `$product->get_total_sales();`